# Eclipse 4.7.2 not showing projects after sudden computer restart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I was working in eclipse, on a 100% working workspace, when suddenly my computer froze. I couldn't kill the broken processes so I had to shutdown the system using my computer power button (eclipse was open the whole time). After the system startup I opened eclipse and... the workspace loads, the theme, code formatting, etc. is there, but all the projects are gone. They are still present on the disk, at the same spot, the workspace just stopped showing them...

I know, I can import the existing projects into workspace and that would fix it, but it would also break the working sets and some other stuff, so... Is there any way in which I could repair the workspace?

Logs from my workspace .metadata folder: [.log](http://paste.strictfp.com/85691)

My eclipse version: [About Eclipse](https://scr.hu/510c/lfsc4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing using an old (almost 3 months old) backup I found out that the file in which eclipse stores workspace file tree is almost empty. But in my backup - it is almost 300 KB. So I came up with three solutions:

1. Just re-import everything to the workspace
2. Take the .history, .root and .safetable folders from a backup and paste the into .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources folder (some projects might be missing and working sets might still be empty)
3. Just backup your workspace daily, like I **should have done** and your loss will be minimal